# pom.xml, **/pom.xml, **/**/pom.xml, then **/**/**/pom.xml... What shortcut to target a file we know its name, whatever its depth in directories?

Tags: linux, bash, wildcards, git

To apply some changes to all my `pom.xml` files, I'm running these commands:

```bsh
git checkout --theirs **/**/**/**/pom.xml
git checkout --theirs **/**/**/pom.xml
git checkout --theirs **/**/pom.xml
git checkout --theirs **/pom.xml
git checkout --theirs pom.xml
```

But I can't find the replacement that would target all the `pom.xml` files, at any level of directories depth they would be.

How can do what I did in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible answers here depending on your requirement. You can't use a shell wildcard to match a file or directory that doesn't yet exist, so you cannot use shell wildcards to instruct `git` on which items to check out unless they are already present in your filesystem. Fortunately `git` itself does support wildcards for exactly this situation.

1. Specifically for `git`, you need to pass the `**` to `git` itself without the shell trying to expand it. In this situation use quotes to pass the string as a literal to `git`:

   ```
   git checkout '**/pom.xml'
   ```
2. Outside of `git` the `bash` shell also supports double-star wildcard expansion. The documentation (`man bash`) writes,

   > **`globstar`**  If  set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

   It's an option in `bash` that's usually not enabled by default so you would need to enable it:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   ```

   Example thereafter,

   ```
   ls **/pom.xml
   ```

Comment: The fist solution didn't work, but the second very well, thanks!